# Positive Solution of Exponential Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation is $2^{x+1}+2^{1/x^2}=6$.

By inspection I see that $1$ is a solution. However, after trying to algebraically isolate for $x$, I was unable to deduce that $1$ is a solution. Given the simplicity of the value of the solution, I was wondering if it would be possible to do so?

Also, I am only looking for the positive solution. However, when graphically analyzing the equation, I noticed that there exists a negative solution that Wolfram Alpha is incapable of giving an exact form for. Does there exist an exact form of the negative solution other than an infinite decimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it is actually possible to isolate for $x$ in this case, however I was able to "algebraically deduce" that 1 is a solution using the following rationale involving the AM-GM inequality twice:
\begin{align*}
        2^{x+1}+2^{\frac{1}{x^2}}
        & =
        6
        \\
        2(2^x)+2^{\frac{1}{x^2}}
        & =
        6
        \\
        2^x+2^x+2^{\frac{1}{x^2}}
        & =
        6
        \\
        \implies\frac{2^x+2^x+2^{\frac{1}{x^2}}}{3}
        & \ge
        \sqrt[3]{2^x2^x2^{\frac{1}{x^2}}}
        \\
        \sqrt[3]{2^{x+x+\frac{1}{x^2}}}
        & \le
        2
        \\
        x+x+\frac{1}{x^2}
        & \le
        3
        \\
        \implies\frac{x+x+\frac{1}{x^2}}{3}
        & \ge
        \sqrt[3]{1}
        \\
        x+x+\frac{1}{x^2}
        & \ge
        3
        \\
        \therefore x+x+\frac{1}{x^2}
        & = 
        3
        \\
        x=x
        & = 
        \frac{1}{x^2}
        \\
        x
        & = 
        1
    \end{align*}
I tried deducing the negative solution. However, I was not able to, nor do I believe it is possible to do so.